# React Native ScrollView scrollTo a diagonal position

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, expo

So I have a ScrollView which should be able to scroll horizontally, vertically and diagonal. It should also be possible to receive a zooming behavior and get a zoomfactor from it. My View looks like this:

```
<View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
      <ScrollView bounces={false} directionalLockEnabled={false} scrollEnabled={false} horizontal={true} ref='verticalScroll'>
       {Content which is larger than the deviceScreen on x and y axis}
      </ScrollView>
</View>
```

I try to implement a diagonal scrolling behavior with the `scrollTo()` function. But when I put an x **and** y value into it, it only scrolls either horizontally or vertically but never diagonal. Inside the panResponder I detect the swiping movement and call the method there. If there a more than one touch I receive a zooming factor which is used to display the content inside the scrollView. The panResponder looks like this:

```
PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
            const touches = evt.nativeEvent.touches;
            if (touches.length === 2) {
                this.processPinch(
                    touches[0].pageX,
                    touches[0].pageY,
                    touches[1].pageX,
                    touches[1].pageY
                );
            } else if (touches.length === 1) {
                this.processMove(touches[0].pageX, touches[0].pageY);
            }
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
            this.setState({
                isZooming: false,
            })
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => { },
        onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
            return true;
        },
    });

processPinch = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
    var distance = this.calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    if (!this.state.isZooming) {
        this.setState({
            isZooming: true,
            initialDistance: distance,
        });
    } else {
        var touchZoom = distance / this.state.initialDistance;
        console.log("Zooming; " + touchZoom);
        this.setState({
            pixelPerMilliSecond: this.state.pixelPerMilliSecond * touchZoom,
        });
    }
}

processMove = (x, y) => {
    if (!this.state.isMoving) {
        this.setState({
            isMoving: true,
            initialX: x,
            initialY: y,
        });
    } else {
        var distanceX = this.state.initialX - x;
        var distanceY = this.state.initialY - y;
        this.setState({
            graphX: this.state.graphX + distanceX,
            graphY: this.state.graphY + distanceY,
            isMoving: false,
        })
        this.refs.verticalScroll.scrollTo({x: this.state.graphX, y: this.state.graphY, animated: true})
    }
}
```

I am **not able** to import any new library, so it would be very helpful if it works with the panresponder.

Comment: Does it work if you ask the `ScrollView` to scroll to a hard-coded position on a button press or something similar?

Comment: this only works in horizontal direction, altough a y position is in the function.

Comment: This may very well be another limitation of the `ScrollView` there are many issues about it and the higher level `VirtualizedList` and even higher level `FlatList`. What you describe sounds something like a map which you can move around... I don't think that `ScrollView` is the component for that. Have you seen something similar done with the `ScrollView`?

Comment: Yes a scrolling ability like a map is exaclty what i want. How can I achieve this? I tried to put a ScrollView into another one, but it had the same effect.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard component for that :/ Either you find a library that provides this feature... or you will have to write it in Java/Kotlin yourself (and also swift for IOS). Meh.

Comment: This looks promising: https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/creating-draggable-component-with-react-native-132d30c27cb0

Comment: It should be sufficient to achieve a "map" behavior but now you will have to figure out how to do the rendering.

Comment: and the problem now is that i dont have an idea how to achieve this. The link looks really good, but how do I scroll when recieving the panResponders move?

Comment: No no, you won't be using a list... well, what exactly are you trying to render? Something like a map or something like excel?

Comment: I try to implement a kind of gantt chart with bars horizontally and the description of those vertically. Should be excel like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209837/discussion-between-elias-and-karl-wolf).